# Set up couldn't find update.inf file

Tags: .net, .net-framework-version, wic

[image]
I need to install a software build in .net platform that requires .net framework 4. Actually my problem is that I have a new laptop and I need to install a .net framework but while installation it give a error as in image I have uploaded. So I searched Google and I found that I need to install WIC (Windows Imaging Component). But when I install it, it gives the error that set up couldn't find `update.inf` file need to update your system. So what probably the error is that I can't install these components in my laptop. For information my laptop has Windows 7 32-bit OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try to do steps below before install .NET Framework 4

1. open cmd
2. type in command "net stop WuAuServ" (disable windows update)
3. Go to Run (you can do this by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>) and type in `"%windir%"` (this command let you go to your windows system folder)
4. Find the folder "SoftwareDistribution" and rename it as "SDold"
5. Then, go back your previous command prompt and run the command "net start WuAuServ"
6. Now, try to install .NET Framework again

Reference: [Solving: Failed to install  .NET Framework 4.0 with Error Code HRESULT: 0xc8000222](http://digitalmemo.neobie.net/2011/08/17/net-framework-4-0-error-code-hresult-0xc8000222/)

Comment: ya thanks..but while installing its taking a lot of time nearly 1 hr and is still installing..wonder when will it complete the installation..neither it throws error nor it completes..

Comment: It depends on your machine. It took about 30 minutes on my machine - i7, 8GB, 500GB HDD.